# Loop through table, look for word in text field, set boolean true if word exists

Tags: postgis, loop, function

I want to create a function that loops through a table and checks if a specific word exists in a text field. If it does, the function should set a Boolean field true. This is what I've come up with. I guess my execute command is wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertCarBooleans()
Returns void
AS $$
DECLARE
    location RECORD;
BEGIN
    FOR location IN SELECT * FROM Ownlocations ORDER BY id LOOP
    EXECUTE
        'UPDATE Ownlocations SET Ford = true
        WHERE 
        cars LIKE 'Ford';       
    END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT insertCarBooleans()
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm missing something, but why do you need a function for this? And why the loop?

```
UPDATE own_locations SET ford='t' WHERE cars LIKE '%Ford%';
```